# Stop/Start JavaScript Increment at Certain Point

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have two sets of `<ol>` (ordered list), and I need the numbers to stop incrementing at the last `<li>` in each of the `<ol>`.  My goal is to make the incrementing start over when it reaches the last `<li>`.

For example, if you go the the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3jthN/25/), and click "list", it returns:

```
1. Hello world! :)
2. Hello how are you
3. good

- Hello world! :)
- Hello how are you
- good

4. Hello world! :)
5. Hello how are you
6. good
```

I want the incrementing to NOT affect all `<li>` inside of the `<ol>`.  I want the incrementing to stop at the last `<li>`.  In this case, `3. good`

In other words, this is what I want to be returned:

```
1. Hello world! :)
2. Hello how are you
3. good

- Hello world! :)
- Hello how are you
- good

1. Hello world! :)
2. Hello how are you
3. good
```

Here is my `function(){...}`

```
function doIt() {
var input = document.getElementById("h");
var olPatt = /<ol>\s*((?:<li>.+<\/li>\s*)+)<\/ol>/g; // recognizes ordered list
var ulPatt = /<ul>\s*((?:<li>.+<\/li>\s*)+)<\/ul>/g; // recognizes unordered list
var ol = input.value.match(olPatt); // returns olPatt match from value
// var olPattAfter = ol.match(/(?:[0-9]+\.\s.+)/g); // this is supposed to return 1.,2.,3.,4.,5.,6, from ol
// var ol = result.value.match(olPatt);
// var olLi = ol.match(/<li>/g);
var ulPatt = /<ul>\s*((?:<li>.+<\/li>\s*)+)<\/ul>/g;
var i = 1;

input.value = input.value.replace(olPatt, function (n, listItems) {
    return listItems.replace(/\s*<li>/g, function () {
    return i++ + '.' + ' ';
    }).replace(/<\/li>/g, '\n');
});

input.value = input.value.replace(ulPatt, function (n, listItems) {
    return listItems.replace(/\s*<li>/g, function() {return '-' + ' ';}).replace(/<\/li>/g, '\n');
});
}
```

Comment: oh no - you're using regex to find HTML elements , you're going to get yelled at

Comment: I hate when people just say "use jQuery" , but in this case Use jquery!

Comment: @ScottSelby  Everyone has been saying this is malpractice, yet I don't understand why.  I'm only 16 and only have about 1.5 yr experience with JavaScript, and I don't see a problem with it.  It's not like these elements are actual elements on the page.  RegExp is  just recognizing characters in a `textarea` that happen manifest into HTML tags!  These tags aren't hard-coded in the DOM.  I would love to know why this is bad practice, if you care to add anything else!  Thanks for the tip, though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restart the counter in the replace callback:

```
var ulPatt = /<ul>\s*((?:<li>.+<\/li>\s*)+)<\/ul>/g;

input.value = input.value.replace(olPatt, function (n, listItems) {
    var i = 1;
    return listItems.replace(/\s*<li>/g, function () {
    return i++ + '.' + ' ';
    }).replace(/<\/li>/g, '\n');
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3jthN/26/)

Comment: So, all I had to do was put variable `i` in the function?!  Well, it does make sense; the variable is assigned at the beginning of the scope.  Thank you, man!